# Replace string which is two lines previous to matched pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a big config.js file and I would like to replace `default:false,` to `default:true,` which is on top of `field:'$scope.keepEffort'`. I tried multiple `sed` command solutions but nothing seems to work.

```
                    {
                            default:false,
                            enabled:true,
                            field:'criticalPath',
                            filter:false,
                            filterValue:'',
                            id:'show-critical-path',
                            operator:'colorize'
                    },{
                            default:false,
                            enabled:true,
                            field:'$scope.keepEffort',
                            filter:false,
                            filterValue:'',
                            id:'effort-constant',
                            operator:'var'
                    },{
                            default:false,
                            enabled:true,
                            field:'$scope.automaticProgress',
                            filter:false,
                            filterValue:'',
                            id:'automatic-progress',
                            operator:'var'
                    },{
                            default:false,
                            enabled:true,
                            field:'groupView',
                            filter:false,
                            filterValue:'',
                            id:'gantt-group-view',
                            operator:'var'
                    },{
```

Comment: You should use `jq` instead of `sed`.

Comment: Ok I searched for jq and found that it is for JSON file but my config file is not a JSON though it look like it from code example I have given but actually it is JavaScript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `awk`.  The following does not attempt to match the single quotes since doing so requires some shell quoting that obfuscates the solution.  Also, a trailing `{` is printed.  That is easy enough to remove, and the code for doing so is omitted for clarity:

```
awk '/field:.\$scope.keepEffort/{gsub("default:false","default:true")}1' RS=\{ ORS=\{ input-file
```

The idea is simply to separate the records by `{` and then perform the substitution (via `gsub`) only on records that match the desired line.

Comment: Thank you very much your solution works but I'm new to awk and sed command so how should I remove the last extra { in file that got added in the same command

Comment: That final `{` is added as the last line, so it's probably easiest to simply pipe this to `sed`.  eg `awk ... | sed '$d'`.  The `sed` command will delete the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/{/{n;:b;N;/}/!bb;/\$scope.keepEffort/s/\(default:\)false,/\1true,/;ba}' file
```

Gather up lines between `{` and `}` and if those lines contain `$scope.keepEffort` replace `default:false` by `default:true`.

N.B. The addition of the `n` after matching `{` which allows the matching of `}`. Also, the return to `:a` after gathering a collection so as to be able to match another `{`.